# MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json - Using MAVEN

Tags: java, maven, post, jersey, moxy

Hi I'm struggling with this error. I have my apimanager

```
    public static ProfileEntity createUser(UserEntity userEntity) {

    // userEntity - userRequestModel
    UserRequestModel uRequestModel = InterviewerMapper.convertRequest(userEntity,MapperImplementation::convertRequest);

    try {

        WebTarget Client = ClientBuilder.newClient().target("http://localhost:8080/messenger/webapp");
        Entity entity = Entity.entity(uRequestModel, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        Response response = Client.path("/interview/users").request().post(entity);

        UserResponseModel userResponseModel = response.readEntity(UserResponseModel.class);

        ProfileEntity pEntity = InterviewerMapper.convertProfile(userResponseModel, e -> {
            try {
                return MapperImplementation.convertProfile(e);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        });

        return pEntity;

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } 
    return null;

}
```

My POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>ca.ciccc.madp202</groupId>
<artifactId>messenger</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>messenger</name>

<build>
    <finalName>messenger</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.22</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
        <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
    </dependency>
    <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support <dependency> <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId> 
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId> </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.25</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<properties>
    <jersey.version>2.16</jersey.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

My resource:

```
    @POST
@Path("/users")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public UserResponseModel createUser(UserRequestModel userRequest) {

    Random rand = new Random();
    int  userId = rand.nextInt(50) + 1;

    // insert into database and retrieve the userId


    UserResponseModel uResponseModel = new UserResponseModel(userRequest.getFirstName(), userRequest.getLastName(), userRequest.getCountry(), userRequest.getUserName(), userRequest.getPassWord(), userId , generateAuthToken(), new Date());

    return uResponseModel;
}
```

and my web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container, 
    see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>ca.ciccc.madp202.messenger</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapp/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And this is my request class

```
package ca.ciccc.madp202.messenger.model;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class UserRequestModel {
       private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private String country;
        private String userName;
        private String passWord;

        public UserRequestModel() {

        }

        public UserRequestModel(String firstName, String lastName, String country, String userName, String passWord) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.country = country;
            this.userName = userName;
            this.passWord = passWord;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        public String getCountry() {
            return country;
        }

        public void setCountry(String country) {
            this.country = country;
        }

        public String getUserName() {
            return userName;
        }

        public void setUserName(String userName) {
            this.userName = userName;
        }

        public String getPassWord() {
            return passWord;
        }

        public void setPassWord(String passWord) {
            this.passWord = passWord;
        }

}
```

And my response class

```
package ca.ciccc.madp202.messenger.model;
```

import java.util.Date;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class UserResponseModel {

```
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String country;
    private String userName;
    private String passWord;
    private Integer userID;
    private String authtoken;
    private Date joinDate;

    public UserResponseModel() {
    }

    public UserResponseModel(String firstName, String lastName, String country, String userName, String passWord,
            Integer userID, String authtoken, Date joinDate) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.country = country;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.passWord = passWord;
        this.userID = userID;
        this.authtoken = authtoken;
        this.joinDate = joinDate;
    }


    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassWord() {
        return passWord;
    }

    public void setPassWord(String passWord) {
        this.passWord = passWord;
    }

    public Integer getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(Integer userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public String getAuthtoken() {
        return authtoken;
    }

    public void setAuthtoken(String authtoken) {
        this.authtoken = authtoken;
    }


    public Date getJoinDate() {
        return joinDate;
    }

    public void setJoinDate(Date joinDate) {
        this.joinDate = joinDate;
    }
```

}

I'm googled the problem and most of the solutions is to add this dependency

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

But I have it already. I don't know what is wrong. Could someone help me out? 
I have tested my resource file with postman to see if I get any response and it is working;
[Link to postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0l0aa.png)

Comment: It's a _writer_ exception, meaning "on the way out". So you should show us your `ResponseModel` rather than your `RequestModel`. If it is working for the inbound request model, that means there might be something wrong with the response model. Maybe you are missing the @XmlRootElement or missing a default constructor. Not sure.

Comment: Thanks @peeskillet. But I'm not sure that is the problem. I'm gonna add my ResponseModel.

Comment: Is this is a client side error or a server side error? Can you post the stack trace?